# Cmd file error with for loop ') was unexpected at this time.'

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I am using this code:

```
for %%f in (*.*) do if not %%f == cleanup.cmd (

)
```

but it gives me the error in the title. At one point I believe it was working properly, but then it stopped working. I am wondering if anyone knows what I am doing wrong? This is not a duplicate as far as I know. (Notice that the error is ")" not "(".)

Comment: Have you tried putting something/anything in the empty () block? Put anything such as `ECHO hi` or `ECHO "%%~f"` in the empty () block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following, the command between the () must be there and not empty.
If the command is not more complicated than this you could lose all the parentheses and put everything on one line.

```
for %%f in (*.*) do (
  if not %%f == cleanup.cmd (
    echo there needs to be something here
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried that... I was using the Tab key instead of spaces... that seemed to be the problem  thanks for helping though!

Comment: It also appears that you cannot have a `::` comment as the last line inside your brackets! `REM` does work though.